# Document File Field Ajax Error

Tags: ajax, webforms, files

I am having trouble with file uploads for anonymous users. I get a non-descript ajax error. It works fine when signed in as an admin user. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot the problem? I've made dozens of sites the same way and never encountered this before.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: I recreated the private files directory and the ajax error is gone now but instead it says the file name exists already no matter what I name the file.

Comment: Anything in the logs for that? Any module installed that might tinker with the file names?

Comment: There is nothing in the logs. Nothing installed that changes filenames. I tried adding the current date and time to the end of the uploaded file in the webform settings but it doesn't seem to be changing the file name before the error occurs.